# Plotly Density Heatmap formatting colorscale and hovertext

Tags: python, plotly

I'm attempting to format the colourscale on a Plotly density heatmap normalised to 'percentage'. The colour scale and numbers look correct but the scale shows 0.015 rather than 1.5%; this is fine for me but ultimately chart need to be presented to people who wouldn't accept that.

[image]

```
sims = sims.iloc[:,f:].stack().reset_index()
sims.columns = ['sim', 'period', 'return']

fig = px.density_heatmap(sims, x='period', y='return', nbinsx=nbinsx,
                         histnorm='percent', histfunc='avg',
                         labels={'period':'Sim Period',
                                 'return':'Annualised Return'},)

fig.update_traces(dict(colorscale='Tealrose',showscale=True,coloraxis=None),)
fig.update_layout(yaxis={'hoverformat':'.1%', 'tickformat':'.0%',},
                  xaxis={'hoverformat':':.0f', 'tickformat':':.0f',},
                  )
```

If I've understood the [Plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.density_heatmap.html) correctly the histfunc should be a property of the z axis but when I look at the generated figure there is no data in 'z' (I'm probably doing something wrong here)

```
Histogram2d({
    'colorscale': [[0.0, 'rgb(0, 147, 146)'], [0.16666666666666666, 'rgb(114, 170,
                   161)'], [0.3333333333333333, 'rgb(177, 199, 179)'], [0.5,
                   'rgb(241, 234, 200)'], [0.6666666666666666, 'rgb(229, 185,
                   173)'], [0.8333333333333334, 'rgb(217, 137, 148)'], [1.0,
                   'rgb(208, 88, 126)']],
    'histfunc': 'avg',
    'histnorm': 'percent',
    'hovertemplate': 'Sim Period=%{x}<br>Annualised Return=%{y}<br>count=%{z}<extra></extra>',
    'name': '',
    'nbinsx': 209,
    'showscale': True,
    'x': array([ 52,  53,  54, ..., 258, 259, 260], dtype=int64),
    'xaxis': 'x',
    'xbingroup': 'x',
    'y': array([0.13911654, 0.14298002, 0.14947634, ..., 0.07539636, 0.07368169,
                0.07359861]),
    'yaxis': 'y',
    'ybingroup': 'y'
})
```

and there doesn't appear to be an option to

```
fig.update_layout(zaxis=())
```

Any help appreciated

EDIT:
[image: screen shot of data frame]

Comment: Can you please show your data if possible?

Comment: @Karthik thanks for looking. I've added a screen grab of the dataframe to the post. Essentially it is 2500 rows where each row is a simulation in a Monte Carlo, the column is the path representing the value at the point in time from 0 to 260 weeks